# [AT91SAM][DEBUGGER]How can I configure the gdbserver with Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, cross-compiling, arm9

I have installed the arm-linux-gnueabi on a VM to cross compile a AT91SAM9G20 software. The cross compiler works fine.

My **question** is: How to configure Eclipse to use gdbserver?

I have configured a new ssh connection (working, I have access on the Eclipse terminal).
But when I click on "Debug" button, I got this error message during file upload:

[image: Error during file upload. Missing element for :"]

The problem seems to be due to transfering file. When I transfer the file manually with scp, there is no trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.
It was a bug when we save the target password on the Eclipse connection.
When I clear the password and I don't 'check remember password' it works perfectly.